# Convert ActiveX text box to table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, cell

Is there an example of a macro that converts each ActiveX text box in a Word document to a table cell (1 x 1). Text formatting can be ignored.

I have this [example for Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4047-excel-convert-textbox-to-cell.html), but do not know which Word objects and methods to use.

I want to use ActiveX text boxes to restrict the size of the text content, which is not directly possible in Word table cells. Also I do not want to insert text form fields into the Word table cells instead of using text boxes, because of subsequent processing of the tables.

Comment: Please do some research with an internet search first. You might start with searching for sites that teach you how to program in VBA. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read my link about how to post a good question. When you have some code to post, we'll help you debug. This isn't a macro-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an example of conversion, which would be more elegant, I have written a workaround that copies the text box content to a 1x1 table. Note that ALL inline shapes are subsequently deleted, not just text boxes.

```
Sub Copy_textbox_to_new_table()
'Loops through ActiveX text boxes and copies content
'Adds table at bookmark named "bm1", "bm2", ...
'Pastes text from text box into table
'NB all text boxes to be copied must be renamed "TB1", "TB2", ...

Dim txtbText(1 To 5)
Dim txtb As InlineShape
Dim i As Long 'counter
Dim tbl(1 To 5)
Dim tblPlace As Range

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 5 '<-text box names must be modified to TB1 ... TBn and value of n is To value here
    For Each txtb In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If Not txtb.OLEFormat Is Nothing And _
            txtb.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.TextBox.1" And _
            txtb.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "TB" & i Then
        txtbText(i) = txtb.OLEFormat.Object.Text
        
        Set tblPlace = ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks("bm" & i).Range
        
        Set tbl(i) = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=tblPlace, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1)
        tbl(i).Cell(1, 1).Select
        Selection.Text = txtbText(i)
               
        End If
        
    Next

Next

'Delete all inline shapes
For i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Select
Selection.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```